# jQuery click() event catch-all?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-click-event

we're showing a box on the screen that I want to hide when the user clicks anywhere on the screen, including body, anchors, divs, buttons, etc... Is there a selector that can handle this for me? Or is it a case of `$('body, a, div, input').click()`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#boxID").hide();
});
```

Since the `click` events will, by default, [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to `document`, this is a "catch all" approach...if you don't want clicks from *inside* the box to close it, add a [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) call on *those* `click` events like this:

```
$("#boxID").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just bind to the click event of document element. Try it at http://jsfiddle.net/ZqEbY/.