# Click event without id or class set

Tags: jquery

let me explain what i do need. I have a navigation which opens by jquery. And i would like to close it when i click anywhere in the site.

I found this one here, but in this case every click would close the navigation:
[jQuery click() event catch-all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761902/jquery-click-event-catch-all)

using

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#boxID").hide();
});
```

But when i click within the navigation e.g. `id="boxnewsID"`, the navigation  `id="navID"` itself closes too. How can i prevent this?

When i try to get a id or sth. which was clicked it only gives the document (logic) back.
I have seen, that facebooks header navigation (message, activity, friendrequest) works the way i need.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us your code, jquery and html

Comment: Which code you need? I have a navigation ID e.g. navID. and a button i click as news e.g. boxnewsID. and the clickfunction which does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(#boxID)", function() {
    $("#boxID").hide();
}
```

EDIT:

That doesn't work, either. Here's what I have in a page of mine:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#boxID").length == 0) {
        $("#boxID").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude one or more elements, you can use this:

```
$(document).not("#boxID").click(function() { $("#boxID").hide(); });
```

This excludes the element with ID #boxID form your selection.

Comment: no in this case not wil not work because i do not get an id when $(document).click This is the problem i described above.