# Click anywhere outside of menu to close menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Even after reading about 20 related questions/threads on here I just cannot figure this out, been trying things for hours but just cant get it, so really hoping someone can put me out of my misery!

I have a slide out menu that currently requires the user to click on the "X" to close it, I need to make it possible for users to click anywhere outside of the menu OR on the "X" to close it.

Ive created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gjjr/pen/abWjjYx) to make it easier to look at the code as theres quite a lot of it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');

    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });
  
      $('.btn-open-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
        $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });



});
```

```css
 header {
     width: 100%;
     
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


 header .btn-open-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    header .btn-open-menu {
     top: 25px;
     right: 20px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content {
     width: 100% !important;
     }
}
 header .header-content {
     width: 30%;
     height: 100vh;
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
     background-color: #FB4D98;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
         left:initial; right: -100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     top: 20px !important;
     right: 20px !important;
     }
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before, header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     background: #F4FB82;
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:hover{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
     
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

 header .header-content nav {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content nav a {
     color: #000;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     line-height: 35px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 1s;
}
 header .header-content .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 40px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 20px;
}
 header .header-content .social a {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 10px;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social a:hover {
     color: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(1.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}


 header.open {
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .btn-open-menu, header.open .logo {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .header-content {
     left:initial; right: 0;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

 .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 4vw;
     line-height: 1.2;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 12vw;
     }
}
 .Menu-list-item {
     position: relative;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
}

 ul.Menu-list{
     padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
     
 }
 .Menu-list-item::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 49%;
     left: -10%;
     right: -10%;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(0);

     z-index: 1;
}
  .Mask {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding-right: 5px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     color: #F4FB82;
     top: 0;
     height: 49%;
     transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Mask {
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
     }
}
 .Mask span {
     display: block;
}
 .Mask + .Mask {
     top: 48.9%;
     height: 51.1%;
}
 .Mask + .Mask span {
     transform: translateY(-49%);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask {
     color: #000;
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask + .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask + .Mask {
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(-5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover::before, .Menu-list-item:active::before {
     transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a class="btn-open-menu">
    <span class="hamburguer"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg"></span>
  </a>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="btn-close-menu"></a>

    <nav>
     <div class="Menu">
  <ul class="Menu-list" data-offset="10">
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="20" onclick="location.href='/home';">
      Home
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="16" onclick="location.href='/about';">
      About
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="12" onclick="location.href='/contact';">
      Contact
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
       </nav>
   
</header>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery click() event catch-all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761902/jquery-click-event-catch-all)

Comment: I dont think so, I just tried the code but because the menu needs to be opened by clicking the hamburger icon, the code now stops the menu from being opened. The code on that question is for a box being shown on the page that I assume doesnt require being opened to begin with

Comment: The principle is the same. Just modify it a liltle bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do it is creating an overlay element behind the header and hide it and the menu when it is clicked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');

    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });
  
      $('.btn-open-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
        $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });
    
    $('.overlay').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });



});
```

```css
 header {
     width: 100%;
     
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


 header .btn-open-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    header .btn-open-menu {
     top: 25px;
     right: 20px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content {
     width: 100% !important;
     }
}
 header .header-content {
     width: 30%;
     height: 100vh;
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
     background-color: #FB4D98;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
         left:initial; right: -100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     top: 20px !important;
     right: 20px !important;
     }
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before, header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     background: #F4FB82;
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:hover{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
     
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

 header .header-content nav {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content nav a {
     color: #000;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     line-height: 35px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 1s;
}
 header .header-content .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 40px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 20px;
}
 header .header-content .social a {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 10px;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social a:hover {
     color: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(1.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}


 header.open .overlay{
   position:fixed;
   width:100vW;
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .btn-open-menu, header.open .logo {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .header-content {
     left:initial; right: 0;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

 .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 4vw;
     line-height: 1.2;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 12vw;
     }
}
 .Menu-list-item {
     position: relative;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
}

 ul.Menu-list{
     padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
     
 }
 .Menu-list-item::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 49%;
     left: -10%;
     right: -10%;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(0);

     z-index: 1;
}
  .Mask {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding-right: 5px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     color: #F4FB82;
     top: 0;
     height: 49%;
     transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Mask {
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
     }
}
 .Mask span {
     display: block;
}
 .Mask + .Mask {
     top: 48.9%;
     height: 51.1%;
}
 .Mask + .Mask span {
     transform: translateY(-49%);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask {
     color: #000;
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask + .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask + .Mask {
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(-5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover::before, .Menu-list-item:active::before {
     transform: scale(1);
}

  .social {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 60px;
}

 .copyright {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 40px;
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #0E0E0E;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
  .privacy-policy {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 20px;
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 8px;
     color: #0E0E0E !important;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <a class="btn-open-menu">
    <span class="hamburguer"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg"></span>
  </a>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="btn-close-menu"></a>

    <nav>
     <div class="Menu">
  <ul class="Menu-list" data-offset="10">
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="20" onclick="location.href='/home';">
      Home
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="16" onclick="location.href='/about';">
      About
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="12" onclick="location.href='/contact';">
      Contact
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
       </nav>
   
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this by using `stopPropagation` in your open click handler, and close the menu in a generic click `header` handler.

### Code

```
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function (e) {
      $('header').addClass('open');
      $('html').addClass('open');
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

You can let the menu open, by clicking on the background using:

```
  $(".header-content").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

[Demo](https://codepen.io/irvin-dominin/pen/eYWjLGY)

Comment: Awesome thanks Irvin, the codepen you linked it my codepen, could you link your revised version so I can see it working please?

Comment: Yep sure, see: https://codepen.io/irvin-dominin/pen/eYWjLGY

Comment: Amazing thanks! Thats SO nearly there, the only remaining issue is that the menu closes if you click on the menu background (pink), is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Check the edit https://codepen.io/irvin-dominin/pen/eYWjLGY

Comment: Thank you, the close button doesnt work anymore though. One of the other answers has solved the issue, by adding an overlay behind the menu that closes the menu when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the window itself so it closes anywhere you click.

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target !== document.getElementById('dropdown')) {
    // remove class here
  }
})

// (e.target as HTMLElement) if you're using typescript
```

Sometimes that can be problematic if you're clicking on an item inside the dropdown and it still closes because of the immediate element not being the dropdown itself.  You can fix that using `contains`.

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const dropdown = document.getElementByid('dropdown')
  const item = document.getElementsByClass('dropdownItem')[0]

  if (e.target !== dropdown && !e.target.contains(item)) {
    // remove class here
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im not sure this is what i need though, are you able to implement your code into my jQuery to show it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. The one that you were missing is `stopPropagation()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');

    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });
  
      $('.btn-open-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
     $('html').addClass('open');
        $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
      $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu2').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
      $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
      
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
      $('header').removeClass('open');
     $('html').removeClass('open');
     $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
});

});
```

```css
header {
     width: 100%;
     
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


 header .btn-open-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    header .btn-open-menu {
     top: 25px;
     right: 20px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content {
     width: 100% !important;
     }
}
 header .header-content {
     width: 30%;
     height: 100vh;
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
     background-color: #FB4D98;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
         left:initial; right: -100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     top: 20px !important;
     right: 20px !important;
     }
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before, header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     background: #F4FB82;
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:hover{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
     
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

 header .header-content nav {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content nav a {
     color: #000;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     line-height: 35px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 1s;
}
 header .header-content .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 40px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 20px;
}
 header .header-content .social a {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 10px;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social a:hover {
     color: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(1.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}


 header.open {
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .btn-open-menu, header.open .logo {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .header-content {
     left:initial; right: 0;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

 .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 4vw;
     line-height: 1.2;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 12vw;
     }
}
 .Menu-list-item {
     position: relative;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
}

 ul.Menu-list{
     padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
     
 }
 .Menu-list-item::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 49%;
     left: -10%;
     right: -10%;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #F4FB82;
     transform: scale(0);

     z-index: 1;
}
  .Mask {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding-right: 5px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     color: #F4FB82;
     top: 0;
     height: 49%;
     transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .Mask {
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
     }
}
 .Mask span {
     display: block;
}
 .Mask + .Mask {
     top: 48.9%;
     height: 51.1%;
}
 .Mask + .Mask span {
     transform: translateY(-49%);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask {
     color: #000;
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask + .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask + .Mask {
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(-5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover::before, .Menu-list-item:active::before {
     transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a class="btn-open-menu">
    <span class="hamburguer"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="btn-close-menu"></a>
    <nav>
      <div class="Menu">
        <ul class="Menu-list" data-offset="10">
          <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="20" onclick="location.href='/home';">
            Home
            <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
            <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="16" onclick="location.href='/about';">
            About
            <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
            <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
          </li>
          <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="12" onclick="location.href='/contact';">
            Contact
            <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
            <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </header>
```